# how convert 13-04-2023 to MMM Do YYYY in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, format

I need to convert  13-04-2023 to MMM Do YYYY in javascript

```
moment(ResData.mDate).format("MMM Do YYYY")
```

I tried like above. But it gives output as Oct 14th 0018.how I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean with `Do`? Can you please provide the expected string for the date 13-04-2023 you use as input?

Comment: i think Do means like 2nd 14th etc

Comment: What is `ResData.mDate`? Does it output a date format that moment understands? I ask because [your code works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/p8ye2mq3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

```js
const o = moment("13-04-2023", "DD-MM-YYYY");
const s = o.format("MMM Do YYYY");
console.log(s); //=> Apr 13th 2023
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

added the `'DD-MM-YYYY'` part so moment correctly identifies the input format and parse the date

```js
const day = '13-04-2023'
const x = moment(day,'DD-MM-YYYY').format("MMM Do YYYY")

console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```